# Is there a hard limit on the minimum height of a button in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'd like to alter the size of my buttons at run-time in order to make them fit the screen well - so, in order to set the width of the buttons, I am doing -

```
int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(); 
int buttonWidth = (screenWidth*2)/3;
```

and then looping through the buttons calling `.setWidth(buttonWidth);` on each one.

I'd like to alter the height in the same way, however when I run my application on the emulator the height doesn't change unless I set it to a larger value.

```
int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(); 
int buttonHeight = (screenHeight-60)/14;
```

I use `.setHeight(buttonHeight);` in the same loop, however it does not appear to do anything unless the value is very large. I've tried reducing the size of the text or the minimum height but this does not seem to have an effect.

Comment: To clarify - altering the width of the buttons is working correctly.

Comment: LinearLayout, sorry. 

I was able to set it manually in the XML file to something smaller, but still haven't been able to set it dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In my experience you can't decrease the height of a Button beyond a certain value, even in XML, unless you also set minHeight=0.

Answer (score 0):

Well - I don't know why the `setHeight` isn't working properly, but there is a better way that you could approach the whole sizing issue.

For the width, if you want a button to fill two-thirds of the width of the screen, then you should nest it within a horizontal LinearLayout, create a blank View, your Button, and another blank View that all fill_parent for width and set a layout_weight like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <View android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>
            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button"
                android:id="@+id/button"/>
            <View android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Personally, I prefer the above over modifying layout in Java code. And while I haven't tried it, I'm sure you could do the same thing for the height as well, but you would have a vertical layout and `fill_parent` on the height instead.